# Find what row holds a value which cannot be cast to integer

Tags: postgresql

I have some operations in heavy rearanging data tables which goes good so far.
In one table with more than 50000 rows I have text column where text should be numbers only.
Now I would like to convert it to integer column.
So:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn TYPE integer;
```

That produces an error 42804: *datatype_mismatch*

By reading docs I find solution:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn TYPE integer USING (TRIM(mycolumn)::integer);
```

But I am aware that data may not be correct in mean of number order since this "masks" an error and there is possibility that column was edited (by hand). After all, maybe is only trailing space added or some other minor editing was made.

I have backup of data.
How would I find which exact cell of given column contain an error and which value cannot be casted to int with some handy query suitable for use from pgadmin?

Please that query if is not complicated too much.

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2095676/263525) hold the solution for you ?

Comment: There are some tip's but I still dont see how to use them in described need.

Comment: I'm only able to get "invalid input syntax for integer" errors when casting to int. What kind of garbage is generating datatype_mismatch errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on @dystroy's answer, this query should cough the precise value of any offending rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_to_integer(v_input text)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        RETURN v_input::INTEGER;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid integer value: "%".  Returning NULL.', v_input;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

Original answer:

If the following works:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ALTER COLUMN mycolumn TYPE integer USING (TRIM(mycolumn)::integer);
```

Then you should probably be able to run the following to locate the trash:

```
select mycolumn from mytable
where mycolumn::text <> (TRIM(mycolumn)::integer)::text;
```

Comment: I switch to original data and cannot find an error (which persist) with that query. I try also "select mycolumn from mytable where NOT mycolumn::integer=index;" knowing that int index and text mycolumn should represent a same number.

Comment: And you've really no idea of what kind of garbage is giving you those error messages?

Comment: I also succesfully try convert_to_integer function which vas recommend by 'dystroy'. That converts all data successfuly. But clean way still gives me: "ERROR:  column "mycolumn" cannot be cast to type integer


********** Error **********

ERROR: column "mycolumn" cannot be cast to type integer
SQL state: 42804
". No, I have no idea what and where this can be caused.

Comment: Hold… a) You're getting the cannot cast to type integer in one case, and type mismatch in the other. Can you double-check and confirm that the alter table statement you posted actually runs without an error?

Comment: Also, the original convert_to_integer by @dystroy will catch and nullify offending rows. It's designed to always succeed. (See my updated answer for a version that will reject invalid input.)

Comment: According to docs 42804 mean "datatype_mismatch" as I can find. Yes, second query from my question converts data but I don't know if this is correct donned. Your function gives me error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
LINE 44:         RETURN v_int_value := v_input::INTEGER;
                                    ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ":="
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1201
I have NEVER before uses a functions so maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: No no, my bad. I changed the function a bit and forgot to change a line. Will fix it right away.

Comment: Your new function also converts without error: "select convert_to_integer1(mycolumn) from mytable ORDER BY index;"

Comment: what does `select mycolumn from mytable where convert_to_integer1(mycolumn) is null` return? If no rows, I'm truly at a loss as to where your error is coming from.

Comment: No, no rows in result. I would have to accept solution which I have (with USING) in hope that numbers are correct as it looks. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Hm, I think once I have similar situation with similar data. I removed '' from text and leave only numbers in column. I think then such error was appear but I cannot be sure what was really happen during a year with this data. I get it today.

Comment: Thanks ! By changing "RAISE EXCEPTION" to "RAISE NOTICE", I've been able to solve my problem and get the offending values not casting to my type.