# Find not-integer values in a string column

Tags: regex, postgresql

How to select records which are having non-integer values in a particular column?

I tried like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE status !~ '^\d+?\$'
```

I want to find all records not storing exact integer representations.

```
  Column   |         Type           | Modifiers 
------------+-----------------------+-----------
 status    | charecter varying(25)  |
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you're looking for non-integer values, if the status contains anything that isn't a digit (i.e. a letter, decimal point, etc.), it's not an integer, so this regex should work:

```
select * from foo where status ~ E'[^\\d]'
```

Note the double-escape of the backslash and the use of the negated character class.

Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6a3a7/3/0).

Comment: You don't need the double backslash if you use a standard SQL character literal: `'[^\d]'`

Answer (score 5):

Postgres uses *signed* `integer`, we need to allow an optional leading minus or plus sign (`+-`).
**Not valid** as integer literals:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE status !~ '^[+-]*\d+$'
```

Note that leading and trailing whitespace is tolerated and trimmed, but not nested whitespace.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1lkoTk0_)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c0825/2)</sub>