# How to Convert text values to integer values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem to convert column with text values into integer values.

In table address i have column 'postcode' type TEXT. I have created a new column name 'postcode_int' type integer. 
In column 'postcode' some people wrote for example '330...' or '00234'.
How can i check if the value is an integer.And if a value is an Integer then how to convert this values from type TEXT  into type Integer and set them in column 'postcode_int' so that later i can do 'between '11111' and '99999'.

i tried to do something like this:

```
UPDATE adresse 
   SET postcode_int= case 
  when pg_typeof( REGEXP_REPLACE( COALESCE(trim( LEADING '0' FROM postcode), '0'), 
                                 '[^0-9]*' ,'0')::integer
                ) = integer 
  then postcode_int
  else 0 
   end;
```

With regards

Andrey

Comment: cast(charcol as integer)

Comment: Or you can do just `yourCharCol::integer`

Comment: if i do it your way  then i get this  ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "388.."

Comment: So you want to convert only integer values, checking it they are in fact integers because there can be non integer values. You must add this info to your question as it is crucial!

Comment: @A.Greensmith The error is because there are rows that can't be casted because it isn't integer values.

Comment: @Jorge Yes I see your comment thanks

Comment: yes, this why i tried case statement. case integer add to column postcode_int else add zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the SQL you need is:

```
UPDATE adresse 
SET postcode_int = CAST(postcode AS INT)
```

This is based on your example.

If this answer is not clear please ask for a revision.

Comment: i get this: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "388.."

********** Fehler **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "388.."
SQL Status:22P02

Comment: Then this is duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082686/how-do-i-cast-a-string-to-integer-and-have-0-in-case-of-error-in-the-cast-with-p

Comment: not exactly. i need to add it to a new column if it is an integer.

Comment: "If you want zeros instead of not selecting, then a CASE statement should work:
SELECT CASE WHEN myfield~E'^\\d+$' THEN myfield::integer ELSE 0 END FROM mytable;"

Comment: Then change the SELECT to an UPDATE and put the CASE against it.