# Postgres SELECT where the WHERE is UUID or string

Tags: postgresql

I have the following simplified table in Postgres:

- **User Model**

  - id (UUID)
  - uid (varchar)
  - name (varchar)

I would like a query that can find the user on either its UUID `id` or its text `uid`.

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id = 'jsdfhiureeirh' or uid = 'jsdfhiureeirh';
```

My query generates an `invalid input syntax for uuid` since I'm obviously not using a UUID in this instance.

How do I polish this query or check if the value is a valid UUID?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Found it! Casting the UUID column to `::text` stops the error. Not sure about the performance hit but on about 5000 rows I get more than adequate performance.

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id::text = 'jsdfhiureeirh' OR uid = 'jsdfhiureeirh';

SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id::text = '33bb9554-c616-42e6-a9c6-88d3bba4221c' 
  OR uid = '33bb9554-c616-42e6-a9c6-88d3bba4221c';
```

Comment: this works for me, not `unhex` or another functions

Comment: This works and it works great for anything with 5000 entries. I work on a database with 6mio entries and this costs 2.6 seconds on average. My solution to this is to use a regex and based on its result, execute a different query: `IF your_uuid_var ~ '^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$' THEN <one_query> ELSE <other_query> END IF;`. In my case, time for planning increased by a factor of 5 and time for execution reduced by a factor of 309.

Answer (score 29):

I had originally misunderstood the question. If you want to "safely" try to cast a string to a UUID, you can write a function to catch the `invalid_text_representation` exception and just return `null` ([modified from an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095676/809572)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid_or_null(str text)
RETURNS uuid AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN str::uuid;
EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`SELECT uuid_or_null('INVALID') IS NULL` will then result in `true`.

In other words (given that `(true or null) = true`),

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id = uuid_or_null('FOOBARBAZ') OR uid = 'FOOBARBAZ';
```

---

**Original answer:**

Postgres will automatically convert the string to a UUID for you, but you need to use a valid UUID.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id = '5af75c52-cb8e-44fb-93c8-1d46da518ee6' or uid = 'jsdfhiureeirh';
```

You can also let Postgres generate UUIDs for you using a `DEFAULT` clause with the `uuid_generate_v4()` function by using the `uuid-ossp` extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE user (  
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   uid TEXT,
   name TEXT
);
```

Comment: I have unknown ```value``` coming in (merging legacy system with modern one) hence the shape of my query (not sure where the ID could be coming from). I can obviously do this on the backend but was hoping for a SQL solution

Comment: @Wainage thanks for clarifying, I've update my answer

Comment: maybe ```SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id = uuid_or_null('FOOBARBAZ') OR uid = 'FOOBARBAZ'```?.. id::uuid

Comment: On 2 million rows, converting ID to string to query took 600ms and doing the above instead took 18 seconds.

Comment: @red6 I'm not entirely surprised (as I've learned more working with Postgres the past couple years), the overhead of running a PL/pgSQL function on every row is going to be much slower than Postgres internally converting to `text`. Perhaps someone might find this pattern useful for other types that you can't do the same, but yes, I'd recommend @Wainage answer for performance in this case.

Comment: I have verified that the uuid_or_null function works on the system that I use.  Though somewhat simple, it really is very needed.

Answer (score 17):

You could check with a regular expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE ('jsdfhiureeirh' ~ E'^[[:xdigit:]]{8}-([[:xdigit:]]{4}-){3}[[:xdigit:]]{12}$'
       AND id = 'jsdfhiureeirh')
      OR uid = 'jsdfhiureeirh';
```

Comment: This answer should definitely be considered by more people. Stored procedures are not as confortable to work with for everyone. In my situation, I'd strongly prefer to be able to just modify a query. My problem was that I had a text column, where sometimes I'd have UUIDs, but sometimes, other data formats. When I have UUIDs, I know that the join should work. This answer was perfect in my situation, because it avoids the casting error completely

Comment: In my case, this solution was much faster, thanks for the help!

Comment: Execution order isn't guaranteed in Postgres, so you can't be certain it will short-circuit in the event that the Regex doesn't match:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL

You could use a CASE statement instead to guarantee it happens in the right order.

Answer (score 4):

In stead of using ::text, use cast(uid as text), and build an index on that expression then Postgres recignozied it for very fast querying. We do that for sharding/partitioning building an index like this

Create index idx_partition256 on  using btree ((right(cast(id as text), 2)));

You can use ::text, but then it is not possible to use I.e JPA since it will be confused with parameter replacement.

Query in JPA could be

“… where function(‘right’ cast(id as text), 2) in (…) …”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i'm interested in this answer, but don't totally understand it. I could use a more complete example. I don't understand what `right` is above, or what the `2` argument is.