# How to write LIKE condition for UUID by Querydsl to find values wich match prefix?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, querydsl

I need to write a code by using Querydsl for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46494463/7750228.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Postgres, you have to use function cast() to do this, because JPQL validator does not recognize this kind of casting. You have a choice:

- Write native query
- Use `cast(expression as datatype)` function instead of casting like this `::datatype`.

The result would look like:

```
SELECT u FROM User u
WHERE cast(id as text) LIKE CONCAT(:prefix,'%')
```