# golang pq sql driver: pq: invalid input syntax for type uuid error type

Tags: go, pq

I'm trying to handle Postgres error.
If user sends invalid uuid - Postgres returns an error with message: `pq: invalid input syntax for type uuid:...`

So, i want to check that error and if the error equals to the invalid input syntax error - i would like to show to the client 404 error, rather than returning server error.

But i can't find the defined error type for the returned error in Postgres library...

Can someone suggest me, where is the error returned?

Comment: Could you add more context? Are you using https://github.com/lib/pq?

Comment: A suggestion: you could validate the parameter before querying the database.

Answer (score 1):

In the query you can cast the `uuid` column to `text`. Here are two ways to do that:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id::text = 'sometext'
SELECT * FROM user WHERE text(id) = 'sometext'
```

Also discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46494463/2316115

PostgreSQL Type Casts are documented here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS