# How to handle type conversion error in Postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was facing an error on type conversion in the Oracle server then I found one of the solutions mentioned below:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('b' default -1 on conversion error) from dual;
```

output: `-1`

As mentioned in the above query, it will give the default value if the value is non-numeric.

Is there any way to handle the same thing in the Postgres SQL?

Comment: You will need to write a custom PL/pgSQL function that traps the error. There is nothing built-in in Postgres.

Comment: Answer in this link will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2894527/5589975

Answer (score 2):

As per [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068104/how-to-handle-type-conversion-error-in-postgresql-query#comment130775380_74068104): PostgreSQL doesn't offer a built-in function like that, but it's pretty simple to make one in PL/pgSQL yourself.

```sql
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION to_number(
    argument text,
    default_result integer default -1)
RETURNS integer LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN argument::integer;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN default_result;
END $$;
```

or, even in [plain SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2894527/5298879) - as suggested by [Vaibhav Parab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5589975/vaibhav-parab)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068104/how-to-handle-type-conversion-error-in-postgresql-query#comment130775697_74068104)

```sql
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION to_number(argument text,default_result integer default -1)
RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL 
AS '
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN argument~E''^\\d+$'' 
            THEN argument::integer 
          ELSE default_result 
       END';
```

Now you can call either by `select to_number('b', default_result=>-1);`. The `language sql` function variant [does not impose any additional overhead](https://dbfiddle.uk/RVeNLliC) compared to typing out the entire `case` directly because it [meets all the inlining criteria](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) so it performs the same while being shorter.

Here's a working [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E4H2CzMg).