How to delete the rows which can cast to date?
I have a varchar column and want to remove rows which can cast only to date



value




01.01.2024


1.2


1


0.6


11.11.2024



I tried this script, but it's work incorrect
select * 
from values 
where value > '01.01.1970'

Result:



value




01.01.2024


1


11.11.2024



I need



value




01.01.2024


11.11.2024



This script is causing an exception:
select * 
from values 
where cast(value as date) > '01.01.1970'


Incorrect syntax for type "1.2"


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082686/how-do-i-cast-a-string-to-integer-and-have-0-in-case-of-error-in-the-cast-with-p

Very few countries use . as a date separator

Lesson 1 - never store date/time values in varchar columns.

See Rationale from Erwin Brandstetter . An example on how to implement . Still the optimal way is to fix table design

As of version 16 you can use the function pg_input_is_valid() to test if some content matches a data type, like a date.
SELECT
    CAST(content AS date)
FROM (VALUES ('foo'), ('01.01.2024'), ('1.2.1900')) AS sub(content)
WHERE pg_input_is_valid(content,'date')
AND CAST(content AS date) > '1970-01-01';

Without this condition, the query will fail:

[22007] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "foo"

And of course you will always use a valid ISO date in your database.

Sorry, To delete rows in PostgreSQL where a column can be cast to a date, you can use a combination of the DELETE statement with a condition that checks if the column can be cast to a date successfully.
DELETE FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name::date IS NOT NULL;


i wouldn't post this as a delete...

How would this work when STR_TO_DATE() is not a function in PostgreSQL? Did you create one? If so, share the code for this function otherwise your answer is useless.

just need to use regex
 select * from values where value similar to '[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}'


Does this accept 33.44.0000 as a valid date?

This regex excepts almost anything, has nothing to do with date. In your opinion this is now a date: foo000x005999999
